# Trying to locate syntax error in python while loop

Tags: python

very very new beginner here - just started learning today! stumped on what the syntax error is here:

```
import random
x = random.randrange(7)
user_start = "yes"
user_start_input = str(input("type 'yes' to generate random number. "))
while user_start_input == user_input:
print("your random dice number is " + str(x))
user_start_input = input("roll again?")
if user_start_input != user_input:
break
print("done")
```

The error message is: 
  `File "/Users/joel/Documents/Learning Python/Dice.py", line 12
    while user_start_input == user_input:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two missing closing parenthesis on the line before

Comment: user_start_input = str(input("type 'yes' to generate random number. " You forgot to close the ( with )

Comment: Please indent properly

Comment: One tip I have when you're learning: If you get a syntax error, 75% of the time it's coming from something on the line above the line the traceback says.

Comment: OP, does your code actually look like what we're seeing here? (You should be pasting it into your question, then selecting it and clicking the `{}` button or pressing Ctrl+K.) If so, the indentation that CoffeeTableEspresso mentions may well be your problem. If that's the issue you should probably take the time to go through a basic tutorial or two.

Answer (score 1):

First off we're (those that wish to answer) missing some information, `while` is on line `5` where as the error is being reported with `while` on line `12`, there's plenty that could be causing an error to pop on a following line; eg. missing quote. Looks like `G. Anderson` already eluded to that last point, as far as errors usually being from a preceding line. My suggestion in this case would be to find an developer friendly text editor (IDE) that'll point out minor typos through syntax-highlighting; [Atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/) is pretty groovy, especially with a few addons, but there's plenty of other text editors to play with.

Second, as commented by `CoffeeTableEspresso` the tabs are non-existent in your code snip! If your source code looks identical to what has been posted, then your bug-stomping has only just begun.

Third, because ya had stated that Python is not your first language it might be helpful, if not now then certainly in the future, to know of `__doc__` strings, eg...

```py
>>> print(random.randrange.__doc__)
Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

        This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
        endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
```

... many of the things within Python are documented and accessible via the `__doc__` method, which can also be accessed with `help()`, eg. `help(random.randrange)`, and it is possible to write your own with the following syntax...

```py
def test_func(arg):
    """
    This is a __doc__ string
    """
    print("arg -> {0}".format(arg))
```

And finally, well for now, it's a good idea when writing in an unfamiliar language to use copious comments and split things up into smaller bits that express your intentions; for example...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random


def dice(sides = 6):
    """
    Returns random int between `1` and `sides`
    """
    return random.randrange(start = 1, stop = int(sides) + 1, step = 1)


def prompt(message, expected):
    """
    Returns `True` if user input matches `expected`
    """
    return expected == str(input("{0} ".format(message)))


def main_loop():
    """
    Returns list of `dice(...)` results, list length depends
     upon number of times `prompt(...)` returns `True`
    """
    roll_results = []
    user_start = 'yes'
    # Set message for first run of loop
    message = "Type '{0}' to roll the dice".format(user_start)
    while prompt(message = message, expected = user_start):
        # Save dice output to variable for later use and
        #  append to list of rolls that will be returned
        roll = dice(sides = 6)
        roll_results.append(roll)
        # For now just print each roll, but this is one
        #  aria to expand upon with your own edits
        print("Rolled {0}".format(roll))
        # Set new message line for following loop iterations
        message = 'Roll again?'
    return roll_results


# Do stuff if script is run directly instead of imported as a module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

---

P.S. keep at it, eventually all the learnings'll start to *click*  and the following RP related example classes will make more since...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import range

import random


class DiceBag(dict):
    """
    DiceBag is a collection of short-cuts to `random.randrange`.

    - `selection`, list of `n` sided dice, eg `[4, 20]` would _stock_ bag with d4 and d20
    """

    def __init__(self, selection = [2, 4, 20], **kwargs):
        super(DiceBag, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update(selection = selection)

    def dice(self, sides = 6):
        """
        Returns random int between `1` and `sides`
        """
        return random.randrange(start = 1, stop = int(sides) + 1, step = 1)

    def handfull_of(self, dice = {}):
        """
        Returns `dict` with lists of dice rolls

        ## Example

            dice_bag = DiceBag()
            toss_results = dice_bag.handfull_of({20: 1, 4: 2})

        Should return results of one `d20` and two `d4` such as

            {
                20: [18],
                4: [1, 3]
            }
        """
        output = {}
        for sides, count in dice.items():
            if sides not in self['selection']:
                continue

            rolls = []
            for roll in range(count):
                rolls.append(self.dice(sides))

            output[sides] = rolls

        if not output:
            raise ValueError("No dice in bag matching sizes -> {0}".format(dice.keys()))

        return output

    """
    Short cuts for dice of a `n` sides, expand upon it if you wish
    """

    @property
    def coin(self):
        return self.dice(sides = 1)

    @property
    def d4(self):
        return self.dice(sides = 4)

    @property
    def d6(self):
        return self.dice(sides = 6)


class Flail(DiceBag):
    def __init__(self, damage_modifier = 0, damage_dice = {'sides': 6, 'count': 2}, **kwargs):
        super(Flail, self).__init__(selection = [damage_dice['sides'], 20], **kwargs)
        self.update(damage_modifier = damage_modifier)
        self.update(damage_dice = damage_dice)

    def attack(self, attack_modifier = 0):
        """
        Returns `dict` with `hit` chance + `attack_modifier`
         and `damage` rolls + `self['damage_modifier']`
        """
        rolls = self.handfull_of(dice = {
            20: 1,
            self['damage_dice']['sides']: self['damage_dice']['count']
        })
        return {
            'hit': rolls[20][0] + attack_modifier,
            'damage': sum(rolls[self['damage_dice']['sides']]) + self['damage_modifier']
        }
```

---

### Updates

Here's what your code block *may* look like with proper indentation...

```py
import random

x = random.randrange(7)
user_start = "yes"
user_start_input = input("type 'yes' to generate random number. ")

while user_start_input == user_input:
    print("your random dice number is " + str(x))
    user_start_input = input("roll again?")

print("done")
```

... and here's what a working version might look like...

```py
import random

message = "type 'yes' to generate random number. "
expected = "yes"

while input(message) == expected:
    x = random.randrange(7)
    print("your random dice number is {num}".format(num = x))
    message = "roll again? "

print("done")
```

... there's little reason to use an `if` *something* `break` when using `while` to do the same kinda thing, well given the current question's code sample.

Moving the assignment of *`x`* to be within the loop ensures that there's a chance of a new number on each iteration, while not stated I've a feeling that that was your intent.

Using `input(message)` and updating the message displayed instead hopefully makes sense. Though I'm not sure why you where wrapping things within `str()`, didn't seem to make a bit of difference when I tested.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like you've mixed up the two variable names `user_start` and `user_input`, so those need to be changed to the same variable name.

Next, Python structures code with indentation: so the content in while loops and the like would need to be indented.

So here, you would indent all the code inside the while loop, and further indent the code inside the if statement inside the while loop.

It also seems like the purpose of your code is to simulate a dice roll each time the while loop runs again. In the while loop, you call on the variable `x` for the dice roll, but `x` is never changed. You never changed `x` to be a different random number, so it will just show the same random number every time the user rolls the dice again.

To fix this, simply re-define `x` each time the while loop is run. So just move the definition of the variable `x` to within the while loop.

With all these fixes, the code works:

```py
import random
user_start = "yes"
user_start_input = str(input("type 'yes' to generate random number. "))
while user_start_input == user_start:
        x = random.randrange(7)
        print("your random dice number is " + str(x))
        user_start_input = input("roll again?")
        if user_start_input != user_start:
                break
print("done")
```

Of course the variable names could be a bit more informative, and the code could be structured better to improve performance and user friendliness, but overall, great job for a beginner!